# Field is null after setting it before

Tags: android, multithreading, android-camera

What is happening:

1. `showCameraApp()` is called. `currentPhotoPath` is set to `/mnt/sdcard/20_08_22_06_33.jpg` (with current date).
2. Default Android application for making photos shows up (`Intent` started with `startActivityForResult`).
3. User is making and saving a picture.
4. We are going back to our application in `onActivityResult()` and `cameraManager.getPhoto()` is called.
5. `currentPhotoPath` in `cameraManager.getPhoto()` is `null`!

Questions (feel free to answer any of them, not necessarily all):

1. Why `currentPhotoPath` is `null` despite setting it before?
2. Maybe I don't have to store `currentPhotoPath` in the private variable, maybe I can pass it with the `Intent`? I tried with `intent.putExtra("some", "thing")`, but later `Intent data` was `null`.
3. Maybe generally there is an easier way to get a `Bitmap` from a photo made by user (without saving to redundant file)?

My blind guess was that maybe it's something with multithreading, so I've added `volatile` to `currentPhotoPath`, but it didn't help.

`MainActivity` class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{
    private CameraManager cameraManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        cameraManager = new CameraManager(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == CameraManager.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = cameraManager.getPhoto(); // HERE bitmap is null!
        }
    }   
}
```

`CameraManager` class:

```
public class CameraManager
{
    public final static int REQUEST_CODE = 666;

    private /*volatile*/ String currentPhotoPath; // THIS VARIABLE BEHAVES STRANGE
    private final Activity activity;

    public CameraManager(Activity activity)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void showCameraApp()
    {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        currentPhotoPath = createNewPhotoPath(); // HERE currentPhotoPath is set
        final File file = new File(currentPhotoPath);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private String createNewPhotoPath()
    {
        final String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_HH_mm_ss", Locale.UK).format(new Date());
        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + date + ".jpg";
    }

    public Bitmap getPhoto()
    {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentPhotoPath); // HERE currentPhotoPath is null!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, that a new instance of `MainActivity` is created when you come back. Therefore, you also allocate a new instance of `CameraManager` which does not have the field set.

Have a look at [Saving Activity State](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#SavingActivityState) in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the data from the intent like so:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }  
}
```

Comment: I tried. `data.getExtras().get("data")` contains only miniature, its resolution is too small.